# Reading a ROS CompressedImage data byte array in C#

Tags: c#, opencv, bitmap, emgucv, bitmapimage

I would like to access the value of each individual pixel value of a 16UC1-formatted png image, which I receive as a byte[].

I am realtively new to image processing in C# and I got stuck at this problem for days now.

I can work with a "typical" bgr8-formatted jpg/png byte array simply by:

```
private static Bitmap getBitmap(byte[] array)
{
return new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(array));
}
```

I tried many things for the 16UC1-format. The furthest i got is:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(byte[] array)
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(640,480,PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);

    var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, 640, 480), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, array, 0, array.Length);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

    return bitmap;
}
```

this at least returns a bitmap, though it is completely black.
Trying `PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale` instead of `PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555` gives me a "General error in GDI+".

When writing the byte array to a file by e.g. by

```
File.WriteAllBytes(filename, array);
```

I can see the image with image viewers like IrfanView, though Windows photo viewer fails.

Reading the file as a Bitmap is not required. I want to avoid file operations for performance reasons. I simply want to access each individual xy-pixel of that image.

---

**Update**:
I started using Emgu.CV and applying imdecode as Dan suggested below.

```
private Bitmap getCompressedDepthBitmap(byte[] data)
{
    Mat result = new Mat(new Size(640, 480), DepthType.Cv16U, 1);
    CvInvoke.Imdecode(data,LoadImageType.AnyDepth, result);
    return result.Bitmap;           
}
```

This again gives me a black image. (By saving the byte array via WriteAllBytes I see useful contents.) I also tried

```
Image<Gray, float> image = result.ToImage<Gray, float>();
image.Save(Path.Combine(localPath, "image.png"));
```

which as well gave me a black image.
I am planning to normalize the Mat now somehow, maybe this helps...

Thank you for your interest and your support!

Comment: If it's `CV_16UC1` (meaning 1 channel, i.e. grayscale), then why do you make the bitmap RGB?

Comment: Hi Dan, than you for your comment! Do you mean to triple each value and then parsing the byte array a Bitmap? My image is a compressed png file. Its size varies and is far smaller than 640*480*2 bytes. I do not know which bytes correspond to a grayscale value.

Comment: Oh, it's not even decoded yet? You need to use [`imdecode`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/c284605a-35ec-b40e-c44d-c83037a6a325.htm)...

Comment: Are you sure that i have to explicitly decode it? I ask since other (e.g. bgr8) compressed png and jpg data can be directly read as a Bitmap. Which opencv wrapper package do you suggest to use? emgu? Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried loading the image with [Image.FromStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for the hint Mike! "Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytearray));" gives me a System Argument Exception: Invalid Parameter in Image.FromStream. I tried with setting useEmbeddedColorManagement=true and validateImagedata=true with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours and hours of wasted working time and despair I finally found the solution...

One important thing I was missing in my description above is that the image data byte[] is coming from of a ROS sensor_msgs/CompressedImage.msg.

The data byte array, which is supposed to contain the png data, sometimes starts with a 12byte header; seemingly only if the data is (1 channel) compressedDepth image. I acciendently found this info [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/247483/decode-compresseddepth-message-from-compressed_depth_image_transport/).

Removing these awesomely obnoxous 12 bytes and continung as usual does the job:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(dataSkip(12).ToArray()));
```